# Model Associations don't work correctly

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-2.0

I have two model. PostModel & CommentModel.
I defined two relation in these classes.

```
<?php
class PostModel extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Post';
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Comment' => array(
            'className' => 'Comment',
            'foreignKey' => 'post_id'
        )
    );
}
 ?>
```

and

```
<?php 
class CommentModel extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Comment';
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Post' => array(
        'className' => 'Post',
        'foreignKey' => 'post_id'
    )
);
}
?>
```

and in database i have posts table and comments table with post_id column.
In the PostController class when i fetch record with this command :

```
$this->set('post',$this->Post->findById($id));
```

and debug $post array i see this array:

```
array(
'Post' => array(
    'id' => '4',
    'title' => 'روز اول دانشگاه',
    'body' => 'سلام. روز اول بود که اومده بودیم '
    'created' => '2012-11-11 21:49:48',
    'modified' => null
)
)
```

I expect that [comment] row be in this array but there isn't.

I search net an debug my app but i can't solve this issue.!!!!!

note : cakephp version is 2.2.3 stable

Comment: It's not normal to name your models with "Model" at the end.  Your models should be `Post` and `Comment`, NOT `PostModel` and `CommentModel`.

Comment: It is according to naming conventions.

Comment: I clear Model at the end. but no difference between them.

Comment: It's not an answer to the question - was just side advice.

Comment: tanx dear [Dave](http://stackoverflow.com/users/673664/dave) :)

Comment: you are right, Dave, missed that one. Of course their is no Model in the model name ;) So just "Post" (Post.php) and "Comment" (Comment.php) to follow conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your models are named incorrectly. PostModel should be Post with a posts table, CommentModel should be Comment with a comments table and a post_id in it. Furthermore, this isn't working because you've told your Comments model to look for a 'post_id' on the posts table as a foreign key. This is not correct for a Posts hasMany Comments relationship, and since that column doesn't exist it's going to fail. If you follow [the convention for Models](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html#understanding-models), you don't actually need to pass anything into the arrays. The ORM will figure it out.

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array('Comment');
}
class Comment extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Post');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you use containable? if not, do so!

public $actsAs = array('Containable');

in your model

and then

```
$this->Post->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Post.id'=>$id), 
    'contain' => array('Comment'));
```

You should also rename your models as Dave pointed out. So just "Post extends AppModel" (Post.php) and "Comment extends AppModel" (Comment.php) to follow conventions.

PS: you can then drop "var $name" from your models. also remove the closing `?>` from your php files. last but not least rename all remaining "var" to "public".

Comment: He cannot drop $name, as his model names are incorrect otherwise.

Comment: Warning (512): Model "Post" is not associated with model "Comment" [CORE\Cake\Model\Behavior\ContainableBehavior.php, line 339]